# Should EventHandler always be used for events?

Tags: c#, events, conventions

I've been merrily writing events using custom delegate types and the generic `Action` delegate type, without really thinking about what I was doing.

I have some nice extension helpers for `Action` and `EventHandler` which makes me tend to use those predefined delegate types rather than my own, but aside from that...

Is there a good reason other than convention to favour `EventHandler` and `EventHandler<T>` over custom delegate types or generic `Action` delegate types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main advantage of the signature `EventHandler<T>` over using one parameter for each member of your `EventArgs` is that you can add additional properties to your `EventArgs` without breaking compatibility.
IMO this is the most important argument. Being able to extent your `EventArgs` without breaking subscribing code is very nice. But of course you can achieve the same with any signature that uses some kind of property-bag parameter instead of a parameter per property.

Then there is variance, `EventHandler<Base>` is convertible to `EventHander<Derived>`, so you can write an EventHandler with parameter `EventArgs` and it can subscribe to events which have more specific `EventArgs`.

Extension methods are another plus, but you already mentioned that.

Comment: I like these arguments. I think I tended towards Action<> because of the inherent extra faff in creating EventArgs classes; will consider my choices more carefully next time :)

Answer (score 2):

No, no good reason.

If your events do not require `EventArgs` or a `sender` object, then you don't need to use `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

**The reason `EventHandler` is convention is that it supports a unified way of working with events.**

The `EventHandler` for example always has a `sender` which comes out handy.

Rule of thumb here is that when you are working with WinForms and creating custom controls or extending e.g. `Form`, you really should use `EventHandler`. For your own classes: go wild.